# Does smartd launch selftests if "-s" option is not provided?

Tags: smart, smartmontools

`man smartd.conf` states that `-s` option specifies the time for running disk tests. Are they run if this option is not provided?

I mean does smartd try to figure out the appropriate time on his own or simply does not trigger tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, self-tests are not run unless explicitly configured.